# Increasing the speed of my code for large matrix multiplication on Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I have identified this chunk of code as the slowest in my machine learning algorithm. I know I am not doing best practices as I am self taught. Can someone please help me increase the speed?

```
rand2 = np.random.uniform(-0.00001,0.00001,size=(popsize,1))
ans += rand2
garbage,sort = np.unique(ans,return_index = True)
sort = sort[:,None]
```

xtrain is the biggest matrix with over 1 million rows and 50 columns. weights is smaller at 50 rows and 100 columns. Before you ask, `ans += rand2` is so I don't get any ties in the `np.unique()`.

Comment: Can you please provide data samples (small ones) that would allow one to manipulate the code?

Comment: Not sure if it would be much use since its the size of the xtrain thats slowing it down. I've narrowed it down to the preds.rank line that is extremely slow

Comment: My wild guess is that the lambda part is the one slowing you down. To propose an alternative, one has to understand the data structure.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is slower than a simple iteration (over rows or columns).  It's only value it to simplify the iteration on a 3d (or larger) array.

Answer (score 1):

Aside of writing whatever you can with Numba, there are a couple of points for improvement:

- `preds = np.where(preds > predcutoff, 1,0)`: the `np.where()` call is useless. It gets significantly faster to just do: `preds = (preds > predcutoff).astype(np.int64)`
- `ans = np.apply_along_axis(lambda v: np.median(v[np.nonzero(v)]), 0, rets)` can be replaced by `rets[rets == 0] = np.nan; ans = np.nanmedian(rets, axis=0)` (but this should be double checked, whether it leads to speed improvement)

Comment: First point - I replaced that line and the two above it with : ```preds = (preds>np.quantile(preds, predcutoff,axis=0)).view('i1')```
Checking your second idea now... assuming you also replace ```ans[np.isnan(ans)]=0```?

Comment: @xxanissrxx I am not sure about that line. You have to check yourself. I guess it is there because it may happen that you get "All-NaN slice encountered" and then the median is NaN.

Comment: Have checked, it produces the same output. Unrelated question - if I throw all of this into a function and use Numba to pass it through the GPU, will that work?

Comment: It depends on whether all the functions you are using are supported by Numba. But it get good speed I think you have to use more parallel computation and eventually rewrite the most time-consuming tasks with explicit parallelized looping.

Comment: ok thanks, no idea what that means but that'll be my next project.